# How to use a while loop for a TimerTask

Tags: android, timer, while-loop, countdown, thread-sleep

I am new to Java-programming and got a question.
I created this code and now I want to insert a while loop so that the text changes every five seconds again.
I tried to insert a while statement and Thread.sleep but it doesn't work.

```
    Timer tim = new Timer(); 

    String rndStr1 = myStringArray[new Random().nextInt(myStringArray.length)];
    txtV1.setText(rndStr1);


    tim.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {

            @Override
                public void run() {
                    count++;

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                     {

                        public void run() 

                        {                              
                        if(count==5)//change the text after 5 seconds
                        {

                        String rndStr1 = myStringArray[new Random().nextInt(myStringArray.length)];
                        txtV1.setText(rndStr1);
                        }
            }, 1000, 1000 );
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow!](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) It would be very helpful for us who want to help you with your problem if you could be more specific on why it doesn't work. What did you expect to happen? What happened instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try
public void run()

```
                    {                              
                    if(count==5)//change the text after 5 seconds
                    {
                       wait(5000);
                    String rndStr1 = myStringArray[new Random().nextInt(myStringArray.length)];
                    txtV1.setText(rndStr1);
                    }
```

Comment: Do I not need to use a while(true) expression, because I want to change the text every five seconds not only two times

Comment: Is the run being invoked? In that case you do not need a while statement the thread will wait 5 sec and set the text every other time...

Comment: I would suggest you to start a new thread and make it wait for 5000 everytime and keep setting the text

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a while loop? If you want the text to change every 5 seconds, just set the timer task parameters to 5000, 5000 and not 1000, 1000. You don't need the if (count == 5) at all. The timer will run every 5 seconds and you simply setText to your textView. What's the issue there?